# Specify a size for ContextMenu MenuItem Icon

Tags: wpf, icons

I defined a WPF `ContextMenu` `MenuItem` `Icon`.

Now I see in this menu images(icons) of different sizes...

Could I explicitly set the icon size of this item?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can specify the width and the heigth of your images :

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem>
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="..." />
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem>
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="..." />
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: I think 50 will not work. 16 is hardcoded in the template for the icon. Otherwise you will just see a part of it.